# How to make not showing of volume dialogue

Tags: android

While pressing volume I want to do some actions without showing the volume dialogue. I use AudioManager to hide this dialogue. But it doesn't work. The dialogue shows up. Please help me.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: 
                AudioManager     mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                     mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                                                      AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
                                                      AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
                 return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: The dialog is shown before method onKeyDown. So 1. i press button. 2. dialogue is shown. 3. method onKeyDown works.

Answer (score 0):

The volume popup won't appear if you use *mAudioManager.setStreamVolume()*, although you will have to handle the increment yourself. You can get the current volume from *mAudioManager.getStreamVolume()*. The value must range from 0 to *mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume()*.

Comment: @user3082303 Not for me on a Nexus 5 running 4.4.2. This seems tied to specific Android versions.

Comment: seems to be a region feature for Europe